# R Package : Feedforward Artificial Neural Network optimized by Genetic Algorithm

Tags: r

and I am trying to install the ANN package from https://rdrr.io/rforge/ANN/ because the CRAN has archived the package from their site.
It is installed, but I don't see any functions in the RStudio and I always have this error message:

```
Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  DLL ‘ANN’ not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?
```

Is there any way to fix this, or can you guys recommend any other package that utilises neural network optimised with genetic algorithm ?

Comment: Why do you think it's installed?

Comment: I checked the installed packages, and it appeared on the list even though it is not working properly

Comment: Then you need to explain more about your setup. The mention of the package possibly not matching the architecture seems strongly suggestive of a failure to do a proper installation.